# Get the latest value of a variable only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that creates a random number when click on the button *(set number)*

Then when you click on the other button *(get number)*, it will retrieve the random number on alert

```
jQuery('.button1').on('click',function (){
    var num = Math.random();
    jQuery('.button2').on('click',function (){
       alert(num);
    });
});
```

Code in action http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/dYTEq/

The problem I'm facing is that when the user clicks on *(set number)* again to get a new number. Then clicks on *(get number)* the alert retrieves twice with the old number and the new number. If clicked them for the third time  it will retrieve triple.

**How do you retrieve the latest random number only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `.button2` click handler defined inside your `.button1` click handler. Make the `num` variable global and set it in the first, and then alert it in the second.

```
var num;
jQuery('.button1').on('click',function (){
   num = Math.random();
});

jQuery('.button2').on('click',function (){
   alert(num);
});
```

See a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/j8zGP/

Answer (score 0):

Try

<kbd>[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dYTEq/1/)</kbd>

```
var num;
jQuery('.button1').on('click', function () {
    num = Math.random();
});
jQuery('.button2').on('click', function () {
    alert(num);
});
```

---

Problem

You are adding `click` handler in the `.button1` click on `.button2` so it is attached multiple times that's why you get many alerts

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that with each click of `button1` you are adding a new event handler to `button2`. Each time `button2` is clicked it will run all attached event handlers, and that will be the same amount as the number of times your click `button1`.

Try separating your event registrations and use a global variable so both functions can access it...

```
var num;//global variable can be accessed by both functions

jQuery('.button1').on('click',function (){
    num = Math.random();//sets the global variable ready to be used by other functions
});

jQuery('.button2').on('click',function (){
    alert(num);//alerts the global variable, as set by the other function
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hj9an/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use closures for this.

```
var num;
jQuery('.button1').on('click',function (){
    num = Math.random();
});
jQuery('.button2').on('click',function (){
   alert(num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dYTEq/2/

```
var num;
jQuery('.button1').on('click',function (){
    num = Math.random();
});
jQuery('.button2').on('click',function (){
    alert(num);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are adding the click event handler to the second button multiple times. Your code basically says "When button1 is clicked, add a click event handler to button2". But a new click event handler won't rmeove already existing click event handlers.

You could do this:

```
(function () {
    var num;
    jQuery('.button1').on('click', function (){
        num = Math.random();
    });
    jQuery('.button2').on('click', function (){
       alert(num);
    });
}());
```

This way each event handler is only attached once. I added the function around that code so num won't be in the global (i.e. window) scope.